# Printing all global variables/local variables?

Tags: c, variables, gdb, global-variables

How can I print all global variables/local variables? Is that possible in gdb?

Answer (score 621, accepted):

Type [`info variables`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html#index-info-variables-918) to list "All global and static variable names" (huge list.

Type [`info locals`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Info.html#index-info-locals-435) to list "Local variables of current stack frame" (names and values), including static variables in that function.

Type [`info args`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Info.html#index-info-args) to list "Arguments of the current stack frame" (names and values).

Comment: @KennyTM,the static variable names in output of `info variables` should be static variables within that compile unit,right?

Comment: @cpuer: Not necessarily. It only displays the name in the symbol table. For instance, with gcc on Mac a static variable `y` is renamed to `y.1913` on compilation.

Comment: @KennyTM ,isn't static variables inside function stored the same way as static variables outside function(in the symbol table)?

Comment: @cpuer: They are stored the same way but the symbol names will be difference. Consider you have a static variable `y` in function `foo` and another `y` in `bar`. To distinguish them, a different name must be assigned to the two `y`'s.

Comment: @KennyTM ,further more,is it possible to get where a variable is declared and defined respectively?

Comment: @cpuer: `info var` does show where a variable is defined for those having debug symbols. But not for locals.

Comment: @KennyTM,seems wrong,`Undefined info command: "var ".  Try "help info".` after typing `info var`..

Comment: @cpuer: `info var` is the same as `info variables`. It works at least on gdb 6.3...

Comment: Note: [there's a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26644) which in short is that `i varaibles` does not print ones defined as a macro. Seeing them currently requires a separate command `info macros`.

Comment: you can also print a specific variable, i.e you have a variable named modified to 'p modified' and will how you the value of the current, or 'p &modified' to see it's address

Answer (score 148):

In case you want to see the local variables of a calling function use `select-frame` before `info locals`

E.g.:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xfec3c0b5 in _lwp_kill () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xfec36f39 in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xfebe3603 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.1
#3  0xfebc2961 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.1
#4  0xfebc2bef in _assert_c99 () from /lib/libc.so.1
#5  0x08053260 in main (argc=1, argv=0x8047958) at ber.c:480
(gdb) info locals
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) select-frame 5
(gdb) info locals
i = 28
(gdb)
```

Comment: (`select-frame` can be abbreviated as `sel`. Alternatively use `frame`/`f`, which also print the frame)

Answer (score 33):

In addition, since `info locals` does not display the arguments to the function you're in, use

```
(gdb) info args
```

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    argc = 6*7;    //Break here.
    return 0;
}
```

`argc` and `argv` won't be shown by `info locals`. The message will be "No locals."

Reference: [info locals command](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/info_locals).