# How to list all variables in the current context in gdb?

Tags: gdb

In gdb, after reaching a breakpoint, I want to list all the variables in the current context, instead of giving each variable name explicitly? Is there any way to achieve this at all?

Comment: I don't think there is single command, but this should be close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261392/in-gdb-how-can-i-print-all-global-variables-local-variables

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You want `info locals`.  Or, if you are getting a back trace, `bt full`.

You can attach `info locals` to a breakpoint with the `commands` command.