# Print values of all global and static variables in C?

Tags: c, gdb, global-variables

I'm trying to see the names and values of all global and static variables in a C program. I've tried using gdb's `info variables` command based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261392/printing-all-global-variables-local-variables/6261502#6261502), but that only prints the names and types, not the values.
I'm currently using gdb, but I'd be open to a different tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

At any time in gdb you may print out the value of a variable with a call to print. On another note, I find eclipse to be a great debugging tool, allowing you to view static and global variables with the "expressions" and "variables" tabs.

Comment: I've used gdb's print and netbeans (not eclipse with this project though), but with both of them I'd have to manually enter every variable in my program, which I was trying to avoid (Netbeans seems to only list locals by default). If eclipse shows globals and statics as well I might get it set up.