# How can I make a step in gdb and show the output of the line at the same time?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have to debug a code segment where I have a lot of values and I need to know the value of each right before I step to the next line. Of course I can do this with 
    step
    print Value
but with more than 3 values this gets exhausting, so is there an automatic version?

Comment: Are you looking to just print the current state of the variables at that point? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261392/printing-all-global-variables-local-variables. Or do you really need to know how each is behaving changing line by line?

Comment: Is it possible to throw an IDE at the problem? You should be able to run your program under test through gdbserver from a full-featured desktop.

Comment: Thank you Guys and Tuffwer - the link to the question answered my question sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell gdb to re-evaluate an expression after each step using the `display` command.  So for example you could:

```
(gdb) display var1
(gdb) display var2
(gdb) display var3
```