# Finding Variables of a C File using Grep

Tags: c, bash, shell, variables, grep

For example let's say i have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 99;
    int *p1, *p2;
    char y[10] = "a"
    // some code
    // some code

    return 0;

}
```

So in This Code, there are two Variables primary of type `int` and `char` . Now, Let's say i make a code of atleast 400 - 500 lines in which i have initialised 20-30 variable. Now, i want to make a bash script to find what are the variables in this code. I begin with this way `cat code.c | grep int` this would print `int main void()` Function in the above given scenario and also print `int x =99` and `//some code` statement, But i want to strictly print those lines `int x=99;` and `int *p1, *p2` Not **Every** line.

So now, here in above question i have a Variable data-type `char` too, Now How do i construct my Bash script in a Way that after `cat` i grep only particular data-type like `int` `char` `double` `float`, Is there any `OR` Method for it? Or are there any easier way than cat and Grep to perform the same??

So my Final output shall be `int x=99;` `int *p1, *p2` , `char y[10] = "a"` :)

Would be looking forward to the responses.

Comment: That is going to be really hard to do with a single regular expression. I mean ***really*** hard. It might actually be easier to write a program that recognizes generic C variable declarations, for example by using `lex` and `yacc`.

Comment: `bash`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk` and alike are not the right tools to do this. A programming language (with a few exotic exceptions) has a complex lexical and grammatical structure, which complete description frequently requires tens of pages of dedicated languages like `lex` and `yacc`, as mentioned by Joachim. Trying to do the same with regular expressions is just a bad idea.

Comment: That's what i thought initially @JoachimPileborg . :( But could it be possible to grep `int` `char` and some other choosen datatypes alone by Using it as OR Method in grep ? For example i did `cat file.c | grep int` gives me the output for lines containing `int` but what if i want to print `char` data-type too, how shall i proceed :)

Comment: Great @RenaudPacalet , I am not experienced with `lex` and `yacc` yet, But shall look forward to it now to process with this !

Comment: You can use `ctags`  for this job

Comment: Could this maybe help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261392/printing-all-global-variables-local-variables

Comment: Also: What do you want to do if an `int` or `char` is part of a structure or union?

Comment: No only the variables which are initialized @Elyasin . But if you have a solution for a Structure or Union also than do share :)

Comment: The C language is complex. It is impossible – read this again: *impossible* – to catch every syntactically correct variable declaration / assignment by using a regular expression.

Comment: @IngoBürk OP wants *int*, *char* and *double* declarations, so it'll be hard and lengthy to do it with a regex but not impossible (like avoiding function declarations and string input).

Comment: Declarations could be split across lines, have comments in between, use macros,...

Comment: Good, Could the Down-voter present a reason here, I have opened that Question category for Answer using Any method. I hope this question isn't too bad

Comment: You can't, you need a language parser like [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). That's why such tools exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a approach with `grep` to find lines that begin with whitespace followed by `int` or `char` using a *basic regular expression* with something as simple as:

```
$ grep '^[ ][ ]*\(int\|char\)' yourfile.c
int x = 99;
int *p1, *p2;
char y[10] = "a"
```

If you have initial `tab` characters, (or mixed `spaces` and `tabs`), you can use a *Perl Compatible Regular Expression*:

```
$ grep -P '^[ \t]+(int|char)' yourfile.c
int x = 99;
int *p1, *p2;
char y[10] = "a"
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, and if not, let me know. There are other c-code scanners that will pull variables, functions, etc out and summarize,  e.g. `cproto` is one I have used and liked a lot. There are a number of others on sourceforge you may want to check as well.

**Explanation (from comment)**

Given the example, it was clear that only `int`, `char`, etc.. were wanted AFTER whitespace (e.g. to miss the `int main ()` declaration). With that in mind we set up grep with the basic regular expression to require at least `1` (`space` using *BRE*) or if mixed `tab` and `space` are possible (using *PCRE*) before the search term. To handle spaces only, with a *BRE*:

```
grep '^[ ][ ]*
```

or if dealing with mixed spaces and tabs, a *PCRE* of

```
grep -P `^[ \t]+
```

Which anchors the search `^` at the beginning of the line and, with the *BRE* looks for a `space` with the *character class* `[ ]`. To handle at least one space, and for `zero` or more *additional* `spaces`, we add an additional `[ ]*`.

Where multiple (or mixed) `spaces` and `tabs` are involved (which cannot be handled easily with *BRE*), the PCRE essentially does the same thing for both `space` and `tab`, while sacrificing some portability for the expanded expression handling provided by PCRE. `^[ \t]+` will accommodate `one` or `more` instances of `space` or `tab` characters before the *search terms*. The `+` requiring the presence of at least `1` or *more* matches of the characters within the character class.

When looking for either `int` or `char`, the basic regular expression format is

```
\(int\|char\)
```

where `(` and `|` do not retain special meaning in a *BRE* and must be escaped while the *PCRE* form is simply:

```
(int|char)
```

So putting it altogether it simply anchors a search for one-or-more `space` (or using *PCRE* mixed `space` and `tab`) characters before either `int` or `char` in making the determination of which lines to display.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Nice. Could you explain the regex portion in the Answer please. Because if i use the same into any other C Code it doesn't gives an output, i think it is checking based on `\t` .

Comment: Would work for a very specific set, but functions parameters declarations, and strings ("drive a char today" (from a Canadian fellow))...

Comment: Yes, this is for a limited set. For larger general source parsing, I have found `cproto` provides a good tool for collecting all the *function*, *variable*, *#define*, etc.. information from a collection of source files. IIRC, it was a package that isn't actively developed, but the sources are still available. The Doxygen suite of documentation tools does a good job as well, but I found it a bit of an overkill for my needs.

Comment: Which program converts the `[ \t]` into a blank-tab character class?  It's not the shell; it's inside single quotes.  I don't think that `grep` does such changes, either.

Comment: A magic shell - blew right by the `\t` interpretation with *BRE*, added a *PCRE* example and cleaned up the *BRE*, thanks.