# How to make GDB + GEF print a list of local variables in context?

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

I am coming from debugging python3 using [`pudb3`](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/), which is a delight. Now I am trying to debug C code in gdb, and I am trying to get a similar experience.

In order to get there, today I installed gef. It looks good, but after searching in the documentation, I cannot find a way of maintaining a list with all the local variables in the "context" view. I know that [`info locals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261392/printing-all-global-variables-local-variables) can print what I need, but I would like to have it at all times in the context view of gef (that I am [redirecting](https://gef.readthedocs.io/en/master/commands/context/) to another terminal).

Is there any way to achieve this? Is there another solution to get a pudb3-like experience on debugging C code?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Was there ever a utility harder to get into? A major hindrance to uptake. Not even a getting started chapter. But a very nice one... ;) You just have to gird your loins and wade through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [custom context panes](https://hugsy.github.io/gef/api/#customizing-context-panes) to gef. Create a file with the following contents, then `source` it in your `gdbinit` file:

```py
import gdb

def get_locals() -> str:
    localvars = gdb.execute("info locals", to_string=True).strip()
    if localvars != 'No symbol table info available.':
        return localvars

def print_locals():
    gef_print(get_locals())

def info_locals_title() -> str:
    return "info locals"

register_external_context_pane("info_locals", print_locals, info_locals_title, condition=get_locals)
```