# I have global variables present during debugging, but they are not being displayed in my debugger. Why is that happening?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb

I have global variables present during debugging(C++), but they are not being displayed in my debugger. Why is that happening?

I just tried to rewrite the launch.json, but still not working.

below is src from c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[100000] = {};

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

fig. checkpoint at `cout << a[i]`

I want to observe the array of `a`.

and in the "run and debug" column, there is neither global field nor static field in the variables (and that might could be a setting error? but how can I renew the debug settings in VS Code?)

and every other has it.

I couldn't figure it out why and how...

below is launch.json:

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "name": "single file debug",
      "preLaunchTask": "single file build",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "request": "launch",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "type": "cppdbg"
    }
  ],
  "version": "0.2.0"
}
```

compiler: MinGW. compiler version: MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.5

C/C++ Extension pack version: v1.3.0

C/C++ extension version: v1.17.5

Comment: note: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6261392/11107541. the list of globals will probably be quite large. maybe it's by design that it's not shown in the variables section (if what you're saying is true). you can still get the list in the debug console